# Subir a base de datos variable JavaScript desde un form

Tags: php, sql

Estoy intentando subir la variable de mis coordenadas en JavaScript a una base de datos mediante PHP. La manera en la que lo estoy haciendo consiste en un form invisible que recoge las id que necesito de las coordenadas y con un submit con POST lo estoy intentando subir a mi propia BD. Pero cuando lo ejecuto me dice que la página no existe, es como si estuviera intentando ir a PHP_SELF, no sé si el problema es que no puedo hacer esto con un form invisible o simplemente es problema de sintaxis que no consigo detectar.

Esto es la parte de PHP

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $latitud = $_POST['latitud'];
    $longitud = $_POST['longitud'];
    if (empty($latitud)) {
        echo "Error recogiendo datos.";
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO registros_jornadas (fecha, hora, latitud, longitud, tipoRegistro, tiempoRegistro) VALUES ('$fecha_actual','CURTIME()', '$latitud', '$longitud', 'entrada','diario')";
    }
       if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
          echo "Se han subido los datos correctamente.";
    } else {
          echo "Ha habido un error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Y en la misma página, después, tengo mi form:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"> 
    <input id="lat" type="text" value="<?php echo $latitud; ?>" disabled style='display:none'>
    <input id="long" type="text" value="<?php echo $longitud; ?>" disabled style='display:none'>
    <input id="tipo" type="text" value="entrada" disabled style='display:none'>
    <input id="tiempo" type="text" value="diario" disabled style='display:none'>
    <input id="entrar" type="submit" value="Entrada" style='display:none'>
 </form>
```

He  probado a cambiar la parte de PHP varias veces, dentro y fuera de distintos corchetes por si fuera un problema de sintaxis y en teoría el PHP_SELF es así como se utiliza.

Si alguien pudiera indicarme si es que estoy haciendo algo mal o simplemente no puedo hacerlo así, lo agradecería mucho. Gracias.

Comment: Usa la herramienta de inspeccionar y mira qué ruta aparece ahí realmente para asegurarte

Comment: Esto es exactamente lo que muestra `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"` en teoría esto debería estar bien

Comment: En vez de usar display: none, es mejor que utilices el input type=hidden.
¿Has probado a dejar el action vacio? <form method="POST" action="">

Comment: @IbaiA. por lo que veo cuando lo dejo vacío no da problemas. Y gracias, lo pondré con hidden.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si dejo el action vacío?

Comment: @Decade si dejas el action vacío, utilizará como ruta la actual

Comment: De todas formas seria curioso que hicieses un echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; para ver que valor tiene y intentar  comprender que es lo que fallaba, que es así como se aprende.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo varias observaciones en tu código, pero vamos por el principio.

1.- No utilices `style='display:none'` para ocultar el campo, utiliza `type="hidden"` que está pensado para lo que quieres conseguir.

2.- El problema de tu código no es `PHP_SELF`, es que tu formulario no está enviando absolutamente nada al no tener el atributo `name`, ya que los valores no tienen una clave para ser enviados, inclusive puedes omitir la propiedad `action=""` y por defecto será el mismo archivo quien se encargue de resolver el `form`.

3.- En tu código php englobas la validación del verbo pero no te aseguras que realmente exista la propiedad:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $latitud = $_POST['latitud'];
    $longitud = $_POST['longitud'];
```

En ese caso, te puede llegar una petición por post, pero las siguientes asignaciones pueden darte un `undefined index` si no se pasan dichas propiedades.
Entonces, asegurate de validar con `isset()`.

```
$latitud = isset($_POST['latitud']) ? $_POST['latitud'] : null;
$longitud= isset($_POST['longitud']) ? $_POST['latitud'] : null;

if($latitud && $longitud){
    // Tus propiedades realmente existen acá.
}
```

Te dejo un ejemplo referencial del envío del formulario, ahora te toca agregar las validaciones.

```
<?php
    $latitud = 1;
    $longitud = 2;
    echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    echo '</pre>';
    
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        die("RECIVED FORM");
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> "> 
    <input id="lat" type="hidden" name="lat" value="<?php echo $latitud; ?>" />
    <input id="long" type="hidden" name="long" value="<?php echo $longitud; ?>" />
    <input id="tipo" type="hidden" name="tipo" value="entrada" />
    <input id="tiempo" type="hidden" name="tiempo" value="diario" />
    <input type="submit" value="go">
 </form>
```